# Spring Security Authorization Server experimental - Maven Repository missing 0.2.0

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

At https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.experimental/spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server the latest release 0.2.0 is missing.

It stopped there with 0.1.2, why?
0.2.0 is out almost a month ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the `0.2.0` release, the Authorization Server [moved out of experimental status](https://spring.io/blog/2021/08/17/spring-authorization-server-officially-moves-to-spring-projects) and into the Spring projects portfolio.

You can find the `0.2.0` version under `org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server`.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server